# How to add a custom pop up on click of 'Add Files' and 'Upload ' button on standard Files Related list on Salesforce Objects

Tags: lightning, files

Below is the detailed requirement-

As a user I want to be able to add attachments to objects in Salesforce that have attachments enabled. Due to legal requirements the user has to confirm that he does not upload any information that is classified as technical information. A pop-up message will prompt him to confirm that the attachment does not contain any technical information in the sense of export control regulation.

After having confirmed that requirement I can select the required document either from Salesforce or from my computer.

Then I can upload the document.

Afterwards the document is stored and can viewed in the related list.

Pop up should  look like this -

[image]
Any suggestions are welcomed

Tarun